# Click cli Python read two file at once

Tags: python, pandas, click, command-line-interface, python-click

I am trying to use `Click` CLI package to read two files at once. Is it possible in Main function to have two option for file paths.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import click
import sys
import openpyxl

@click.command(help="count")
@click.option("-i", "--input", "infile", type=click.File(), default=sys.stdin, help="Input file name")
@click.option("-i1", "--input1", "infile1", type=click.File(), default=sys.stdin, help="Input file name2")


def main(infile, infile1):
    """_summary_
    Use click command to run count_unique_port from CLI

    Args:
        infile (_type_): input folder directory
        outfile (_type_): output folder directory
    """
    nav = pd.read_csv(infile)
    print(nav)
    
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(infile1)
    wb = wb['Up']
    sheet = wb

    # Create an empty DataFrame
    data = []

    # Iterate over the rows in the sheet
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=38, values_only=True):
        data.append(row)

    # Convert to DataFrame
    ubs_var = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(ubs_var)



# test var metrics
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    main()
```

Once I try to run it `python reporting/generate_cli.py --input ./reporting/data/f1.csv --input1 ./reporting/data/f2.xlsx`

I stumble upon this error  raise `BadZipFile("File is not a zip file") zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

How I can read two files providing two paths to them? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not related to `Click`package. It is related to how we can read binary files from disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).